# Spotify API Node - Wrong Session

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, cookies, spotify

I'm currently having issues with multiple users seeing on the wrong things on my web app. So, `user A` would login and see their details, then `user B` would login and see their details, which is fine. But when `user A` refreshes the page, they see `user B's` details. How would I make it keep `user A's` details even if refreshed (with `user B` still logging in after)?

Here's what I currently have:

```
var express = require('express');
var SpotifyWebApi = require('spotify-web-api-node');
var path = require('path');
var chartify = require('./app.js');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

var app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname + '/views'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/views')).use(cookieParser());

var port = process.env.PORT || 8000;

var client_id = '';
var client_secret = '';
var redirect_uri = '';
var stateKey = 'spotify_auth_state';

var spotifyApi = new SpotifyWebApi({
    clientId: client_id,
    clientSecret: client_secret,
    redirectUri: redirect_uri
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index');
});

app.get('/login', function(req, res){
    var state = chartify.generateRandomString(16);
    var scope = ['user-top-read'];
    res.cookie(stateKey, state);

    var authorizeURL = spotifyApi.createAuthorizeURL(scope, state)
    res.redirect(authorizeURL);

});

app.get('/callback', function(req, res) {
    var state = req.query.state || null;
    var storedState = req.cookies ? req.cookies[stateKey] : null;

    if (state == null || state != storedState) {
        res.redirect('/#/state-mismatch');
    } else {
        res.clearCookie(stateKey);
        spotifyApi.authorizationCodeGrant(req.query.code).then(function(data) {
            spotifyApi.setAccessToken(data.body.access_token);
            spotifyApi.setRefreshToken(data.body.refresh_token);  

            res.redirect('/details');
        });
    }

});

app.get('/details', function(req, res) {
    var access_token = spotifyApi.getAccessToken()

    if (access_token == undefined || null) {
        res.redirect('/')
        return;
    }

    //do things
    res.render('template.ejs')

});


app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('APP LISTENING ON PORT 8000.');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Each user has their own `access_token`, however when they visit `/details` you just get the last access_token that was set on your server side instance of `spotifyApi` using `spotifyApi.getAccessToken()`.

So if user A logged in, and then user B logged in, user A would indeed see the details of user B since the call to `/details` is being made using the `spotifyApi` instance that still has the `access_token` of user B.

You need to have a way to differentiate between which user is calling `/details` and use the appropriate token. The easiest way would be for the client to know their own token and have them send that along in the request to your server.